# How do I wrap the output of a Jupyter notebook code execution result in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, output

[image: This is the my current output]

This is the my current output.^ I have to scroll to check the whole output text.

[image: I want something similar to this, this is just an example, I want the output to break depending on the window size of my vscode width.]

I want the output to break to a new line depending on the window size of my vscode window width. ^